# How to use DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am not new to java but just recently practicing about jdbc. I'm trying to fetch data from mysql database and load it to jtable..

here's my code for fetching the data class name FileMaintenance

```
public DefaultTableModel getProducts()
{
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    try{

        dtm.addColumn("Product Code");
        dtm.addColumn("Description");
        dtm.addColumn("Unit Price");
        dtm.addColumn("Selling Price");

        conn.stmt = conn.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        sql = "SELECT prodcode,proddesc,origprice,sellingprice FROM products";
        rs = conn.stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            String code = rs.getString(1);
            String desc = rs.getString(2);
            String uprice = rs.getString(3);
            String sprice = rs.getString(4);

            dtm.addRow(new String[]{code,desc,uprice,sprice});
        }
        return dtm;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to fetch data...","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and there as the line that I used to call the method from FileMaintenance class

```
public void UpdateJTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel model = new FileMaintenance().getProducts();
    jtable.setModel(model);
}
```

now when I try to run the app, it says I'm connected to database which is true because I already tried inserting data and its successful, but there's an error occur. the error is related to DefaultTableModel because its point to line

```
DefaultTableModel model = new FileMaintenance().getProducts();
jtable.setModel(model);
```

it says:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at MyForm.UpdateJTable(MyForm.java:119)
>           at MyForm$1.windowOpened(MyForm.java:104)
>           at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2048)
>           at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:296)
>           at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)

```
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

could someone please tell me what is the problem with this code?

Comment: *"but there's an error occur" - which would be what exactly? *"he error is related to DefaultTableModel" - How?

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Without any runnable code it's impossible for use to deduce a `NullPointerException`.  You should place debug statements into your code to output the states of your variables and use a debugger to inspect the values at runtime